# Minecraft acting differently when started from terminal compared to started by cron job at start-up

Tags: centos, cron, java, minecraft

So I use a CentOS Linux 7.2.1511 server, where I host a couple of things, amongst them a Minecraft server. Since from time to time server is rebooted I scheduled a cron job to run minecraft server on boot, the command being:

```
cd /home/username/minecraft && java -jar craftbukkit-1.9.jar
```

This does a fine job with the exception of that for some unknow reason the process is then using huge percentage of CPU.
On the other hand whan I use putty to access my server then go to my minecraft folder and run command

```
java -jar craftbukkit-1.9.jar
```

there manually, there is no overusing of the CPU.
So anyone has any idea why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: It's likely that your interactive environment and `cron`'s environment are set up differently, possibly even using different implementations of `java` if the `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` variables are pointing to different JREs.

Comment: ok I see, is there a way I can check these environments to compare them and set cron's to be like my interactive one when this command is run ?

Comment: the easiest way to test the 'running different JREs' hypothesis is to run `java -version` and compare that to the file created by a `cron` job you can set up to run `java -version > /home/username/cron-java-version.txt`

Comment: well, both commands gave the same output, so it seems it is not a case of different JRE's